# Which one is Faster, SUB-Query or IN-Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, subquery

If I want to select `whether i am following` the `thread`s or not.

I have two approaches to do so... but I don't know which one would be more better in terms of performance and speed. Can anyone help me out?

### Approach 1

```
$cui = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$data  = mysqli_query($con,"
SELECT t.*,( select count(follow_id) from follows where object_id = 
t.thread_id AND object_type='thread' AND user_id = $cui) as me_follow FROM threads t
");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
       /*
           $row['me_follow'] = 0 if i aint following
           $row['me_follow'] = 1 if  i am following  
       */
   }
```

### Approach 2

```
$cui = $_SESSION['user_id'];

  $data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM threads");
  $ids = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
       $ids[] = $row['thread_id'];
   }
$ids = join($ids,",");
$data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM follows WHERE object_id IN($ids) AND user_id = $cui");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One round-trip wins over two.  This is because there is some overhead in sending SQL to the server, having it parse it, execute it and send the results back.  It is (usually) better to do everything in one round-trip.

Comment: 1 for "One round-trip wins over two". Thanks